# Custom domain in firebase: Cannot get TXT record type in my .com.bd domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to connect firebase hosting to a custom domain. Firebase is providing a TXT record. But I have a .com.bd domain where there is no place to add record(TXT, cname etc). There is only place for Primary Domain Name Server(DNS), Secondary Domain Name Server(DNS) and Tertiary Domain Name Server(DNS).

Is there any way to connect firebase to this domain? or what do you suggest me to do in this situation?

Comment: A primary DNS server is something you configure in a client. With Firebase Hosting you need to edit the zone file of your DNS provider, which is the opposite side of things. You'll want to reach out to your registrar/provider on how to add the TXT record. Typically if you search for the name of your registrar and how to edit the DNS zone file, there may be some good search results.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your reply... i was missing out the dns provider part. Now its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing out the dns provider part in the whole process. I am using namecheap dns.

I have added dns provider's provided nameservers as Primary and Secondary Domain Name Server. After connecting with the dns i have access to the cpanel. 
In cpanel:

1. In the 'Domains' section i have added new domain.
2. In the 'Zone Editor' section i can 'ADD RECORD' to that specific domain buy clicking on the 'Manage' button